# Reading hundred thousands of images into MAT file

Tags: image, matlab, bigdata

I have 400.000 images waiting to be written on a Mat file. My current procedure is to read all the images into a matrix and save the matrix at the end. But it really time consuming especially at the later stages of the reading. It is slowing down gradually. Is there any other way to deal such a problem in MATLAB?

Comment: Did you profile this? How much does it take to read a single image?

Comment: It starts faster but getting slower and slower in the course of time. Therefore measures are not indicative enough. However for 100x100 images of 100.000 after first 10.000 it takes ~3sec to load one image

Comment: how do you add the images into the matrix? Sounds like you are not pre-allocating memory and this is why you experience gradual slow-down.

Comment: Can you really pre-allocate memory in this case? 100000 x 100 x 100 is greater than the maximum variable size on my system (depends on system and possibly on Matlab version, but see http://www.mathworks.co.uk/support/solutions/en/data/1-IHYHFZ/index.html ).

Comment: @Shai I have a collection of folders I am passing over one to another. I read all the images of a folder into a matrix by adding it incrementally instead of defining a matrix before the iteration. At the end I merge all those matrices. But your saying is possible to be a cause of slowing down. I will try with preallocation

Comment: @nkjt  I am working on a workstation so it might be allocated at this configuration but you're right for the PCs

Comment: Preallocation is the first step, then you need to avoid memory swapping if you are on 64bit. If you end up consuming all of your RAM, you will start swapping on HD, which will make it much slower.

Comment: Do you really need to have all of them open? What are you doing with them - what is your merge operation? Could you open in batches, & perform a partial merge? Preallocation of 400000 100x100 uint8s takes 4GB on my system, and it is possible - make sure you are preallocating to uint8 `x=ones([100,100,400000],'uint8');`! It takes 8 times less memory than a matrix of doubles, which is the default preallocation if you don't specify otherwise. If these are color images, you'll have to multiply those numbers by 3.